# Get variables from php file to bash sh script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Im building a shell script to automate some process on my work.

I need to pull some variables from a php they are created like this:

```
return [

    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'dbname',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

So, my plan was to pull the php file this way:

```
#!/bin/bash  
# php file to get variables from
FILE_NAME="etc/env.php"
echo "Starting Migration..."  
DATABASE=$(cat $FILE_NAME | grep "^\'dbname' =>" | cut -d "=" -f 2-) 
DATABASE_HOST=$(cat $FILE_NAME | grep "^\host=" | cut -d "=" -f 2-)
DATABASE_PASS=$(cat $FILE_NAME | grep "^\password=" | cut -d "=" -f 2-)
DATABASE_USER=$(cat $FILE_NAME | grep "^\$username=" | cut -d "=" -f 2-)
echo "Value from PHP file"
echo "Database name ${DATABASE}"
echo "Database host ${DATABASE_HOST}"
echo "Database pass ${DATABASE_PASS}"
echo "Database user ${DATABASE_USER}"
```

But im not getting the variables , its just empty...any ideas?

Comment: Is `FILE_NAME` supposed to be "`etc/env.php`" or "`/etc/env.php`"? Do any of the subexpressions work? What does `cat $FILE_NAME | grep "^\'dbname' =>" | cut -d "=" -f 2-` do on its own? Why `cat $FILE_NAME | grep expression`? `grep expression $FILE_NAME` is better. There's http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Yes, this command DATABASE=$(cat $FILE_NAME | grep "dbname" | cut -d "=" -f 2-) seems to be working, but im getting some characters i dont need, im getting with that call: > 'dbname', , so i just need to get dbname

Comment: You could `grep expression $FILE_NAME | cut "-d'" -f4`, that is use "`'`" as the delimiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU `grep` if available, you can do this

```
grep -Po "(?<='dbname' => ).*(?=,)" file
```

In your script:

```
DATABASE=$(grep -Po "(?<='dbname' => ).*(?=,)" $FILE_NAME) 
DATABASE_HOST=$(grep -Po "(?<='host' => ).*(?=,)" $FILE_NAME) 
DATABASE_PASS=$(grep -Po "(?<='password' => ).*(?=,)" $FILE_NAME) 
DATABASE_USER=$(grep -Po "(?<='username' => ).*(?=,)" $FILE_NAME)
```

With the `-P` option you activate Perl-like regular expressions.

With the `-o` option you get *only* the captured string, not the whole line.

Basically this happens:

```
(?<=<string starts with>)<capture this string>(?=<string ends with>)
```

Comment: This is close, im getting  etc/env.php:'localhost' , i need get only localhost.

Comment: Sorry I edited the answer, there was an error: `file $FILE_NAME` is just `$FILE_NAME`

Comment: Thank you, its working, just getting: Database host 'localhost' can we remove the ' and just get Database host localhost ? can you explain what are you doing?

Comment: I edited the answer, hopefully it's clear. To remove the single quotes you just need `"(?<='dbname' => ').*(?=',)"`. Do you want me to add that to the answer?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the final result:
DATABASE=$(grep -Po "(?<='dbname' => ').*(?=',)" $FILE_NAME) 
DATABASE_HOST=$(grep -Po "(?<='host' => ').*(?=',)" $FILE_NAME) 
DATABASE_PASS=$(grep -Po "(?<='password' => ').*(?=',)" $FILE_NAME) 
DATABASE_USER=$(grep -Po "(?<='username' => ').*(?=',)" $FILE_NAME)

Comment: Pure magic ! Just what I need +1 !

Comment: My variable is saved in the file as -  `$db_host = "blabla.rds.amazonaws.com";` So, I used this systex and it worked for me  -  `DB_HOST=$(grep -Po '(?<='db_host' = ").*(?=";)'` $FILE_NAME)

Answer (score 0):

Typically for each feature a shell script needs that isn't within the scope of shell scripting, it calls some other program that will "do one thing well" (Unix philosophy) so why not call the program that does what you want to do? You may not have realized that you can run PHP directly from the command line (or shell script in this case) using the PHP `-r` argument. Here is how to do it with your example (Assuming the input file starts with `<?php` and ends with `; ?>` instead of `,`), by using the require statement to use the return of the php file as an array (which it is in your case):

```
DATABASE=$(php -r 'echo (require("input.php"))["db"]["connection"]["default"]["dbname"];')
DATABASE_HOST=$(php -r 'echo (require("input.php"))["db"]["connection"]["default"]["host"];')
DATABASE_PASS=$(php -r 'echo (require("input.php"))["db"]["connection"]["default"]["password"];')
DATABASE_USER=$(php -r 'echo (require("input.php"))["db"]["connection"]["default"]["username"];')
```

If the PHP file doesn't have a return within the global scope, follow the require statement with `;` then do a separate echo statement (The `-r` argument can accept multiple lines if each ends with semicolon. See my answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747009/343286).